# Comparing versions with Fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I need to compare the version of the installed maven package with a minimum version, using fabric. That's a simple x.y.z version number. Is there any fabric or python library with a function to do that, or a simple way of doing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trick to do it, used by Python itself:

```
def versioncmp(current, required):
    current = [int(i) for i in current.split('.')]
    required = [int(i) for i in required.split('.')]
    return current >= required
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to do it on one machine then

```
import subprocess, re
match=re.compile(r'Apache Maven ([0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])')
version=subprocess.check_output('mvn --version',shell=True)
version_number=match.search(version).group(1)
```

Otherwise you can replace subprocess.check_output with Fabric's `run` command.

Comment: Grabbing the version number is easy. The question is how to compare what was grabbed in a meaningful way.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral Ah, is it not sufficient to remove the periods cast it to an integer and do a comparison? Otherwise I would suggest using a configuration management tool such a salt stack to ensure a minimum version is installed.

Comment: Well, I'm using Fabric.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral All right. Fabric is very DIY, it gives you parallel remote execution but that's about it. So you have to write your own scripts to do whatever you need, which you can then execute wherever you want.